# Moving images with MouseWheel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move an image from side to side using the mousewheel. The image by default is set to absolute position and left=100px. It is not allowing for the scroll to move the image with the parseInt but if I take that out it moves immediately to left=0px. I want to be able to move it a few pixels for each wheel click.

```
 window.onload = function() {
        if (document.body.addEventListener) {
                document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
                document.body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
        }
        else document.body.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);

        function MouseWheelHandler(e){
            // cross-browser wheel delta
        var e = window.event || e; // old IE support
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

        img1.style.left = Math.max(0, Math.min(1100, parseInt(img1.style.left) + (delta))) + "px";

        return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that event! It's not well supported and could give you headaches.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mousewheel

Comment: I have to use it for a class. i normally wouldn't.